# javascript - dispatchEvent return true but not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, dispatchevent

There are some web,I type the code below not working.For example,I type the code in console at Bing(a search engine)

```
var event;
event = document.createEvent('Event');
event.initEvent("keypress", true, true);
event.view = window;
event.keyCode = 13;
event.which = 13;
event.charCode = 13;
event.code = "Enter";
event.key = "Enter";
event.bubbles = true;
```

and i have already type some text in the search bar, the element's id is "sb_form_q",so

```
var element = document.getElementById("sb_form_q");
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

it will return true, but actually nothing happen.
I have tried many webs, some working, some not working, and i don't know why.

2018/8/3 update:

I know why some web page dispatch "Enter" event don't work,cause the input is not submit by "Enter" key, but by submit or onsubmit event.

Comment: I am writing a google extension, and i want to auto type the text and submit it, now i can successfully auto type the text, but can't dispatch "enter"

Comment: Use JavaScript to simulate press "Enter" key is important for me

Answer (score 1):

Please find below example as well for **`Enter`** keyword.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var ev = document.createEvent('Events');
    ev.initEvent('keypress', true, true);
    ev.keyCode = 13;
    ev.which = 13;
    ev.charCode = 13;
    ev.key = 'Enter';
    ev.code = 'Enter';
    var eventReturns = document.querySelector('#input-event').dispatchEvent(ev);    
    var Inputvalue = document.getElementById('input-event').value;
    console.log({isdispatch: eventReturns, value: Inputvalue}); 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-event" value="Hello World" />
```

Comment: keypress event with key **`Enter`**

Comment: yeah, it can work like my code, but in search engine "Bing" or some webs, still not working.My purpose is that i can use the code in every web.

Comment: I have tested with below Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Edge etc.

Comment: [Inline Link](cl.ly/0G1D2j0y0N1k) (cl.ly/3S1f3G2x0y1P)(cl.ly/442V0f2n1C2I)(cl.ly/3S3T0a0r2j1L)

Comment: Sorry for my poor english,the thing i think is i want to execute in webs(such as Ask.com,and Bing.com,etc) in the search box, not web browsers.
i find it is difficult to test in console in web, because i write it in my plugin .
However,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code it's working.

```js
function MouseEvent(event) {
 var x = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
 x.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

 document.getElementById("myDiv").dispatchEvent(x);
 console.log(document.getElementById("myDiv").dispatchEvent(x));
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<button onclick="MouseEvent(event)">Simulate click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks,but the method I want is to simulate a user that types the input and press "enter" key